# meteor app: how to properly retrieve a single document from a collection on the client

Tags: javascript, meteor

In my meteor app I'm storing the client's unique id string in a collection called UserNavigationTracker:

```
{
    "clientId" : "xxNfxxPGi7tqTbxc4",
    "currentWizard" : "IntroductionWizard",
    "currentStep" : "Step-1",
    "_id" : "ifBJ688upEMfzzviC"
}
```

As a part of the app initialization, I need to check and see if information about my client is already stored in the database.
I'm struggling with retrieving this record back from the collection.
Here is what I'm doing:

```
var clientIdInDatabase = UserNavigationTrackerCollection.find({"clientId": "xxNfxxPGi7tqTbxc4"});
console.log('clientIdInDatabase:  ' + clientIdInDatabase);
```

The browser console output from this is:  clientIdInDatabase:  [object Object]

Mt question is: how can I get the actual value of the clientId field from this returned Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` returns a cursor, just replace it with `findOne` to get a single object (or undefined). If you ever want to get more than one document, you can get an array of them with `find(...).fetch()`. You can read the documentation for all of these functions in [this section](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection) of the docs.

---

Based on our discussion, this may work on the client to compensate for the subscription delay:

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  var clientId = Session.get('clientId');
  var unt = UserNavigationTrackerCollection.findOne({clientId: clientId});
  Session.set('isClientIdInDatabase', unt != null);
});
```

Note this assumes that `clientId` and `isClientIdInDatabase` are stored in session variables.

Comment: when I use findOne - I get undefined instead of an object.

Comment: If you get `undefined` with `findOne` it means the object you are looking for was not found. Check your selector, and check the contents of the database itself. If you are running in dev mode (default) you can do: `$ meteor mongo` on the command line to get access to the local meteor db shell.

Comment: This is very strange - when I issue command  UserNavigationTrackerCollection.findOne() from the browser console - I get the expected result. Exactly same syntax within my app returns undefined

Comment: Is this running on the client? If so, then your find is probably just executing before the data has arrived in minimongo.

Comment: Yes, this is running on the client. The only code on the server is the definition of the UserNavigationTrackerCollection. Should I be calling "find()" some place else?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the rest of the project. I added an example `autorun` which you can place anywhere on the client. It should set a session variable whenever the data becomes available.

Comment: This autorun works as designed. The remaining question is: is  there a way to trigger a callback when the value of isClientIdInDatabase becomes true? Another words, is there a way to detect and react when the minimongo data becomes available

Comment: Yeah that's why I put the value in a session variable - you can use it in a template helper and it will update as soon as the value changes. Alternatively, you could replace the `Session.set` with an `if`. For example, `if(unt != null){console.log('it just changed!');}`